# Using jQuery with apex:tabPanel in visualforce

Tags: javascript, jquery, visualforce, force.com

I am using jQuery library in my visual force page, but I've faced a major problem when I tried to use tabs "apex:tabPanel".

```
<script src="{!$Resource.jQuery}"></script> <!-- If I delete this script the tabs work !! -->

<apex:tabPanel tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">
  <apex:tab label="Tab#1" id="tab1"></apex:tab>
  <apex:tab label="Tab#2" id="tab2"></apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

I get a "JS" errors in the console when I try to click on any tab, but if I delete jQuery library it works. So I guess there is a conflict between jQuery and apex:tabPanel functionality.

---

Here's what I got in the console

> ```
> Uncaught ReferenceError: initViewstateTab is not defined 
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dispatchEvent' 
> Uncaught ReferenceError: initViewstateTab is not defined 
> event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hasClassName' 
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
> ```

Comment: What error are you getting in console.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar I edited the question, check it out.

Comment: can you show your .js include files

Comment: Have you defined CSS class which you are using (activetab & inactivetab)

Comment: @Nomi the only script that I use is the jQuery library, otherwise it will be built in force.com platform.

Comment: @SravanAlaparthi yes I did

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error happens here because of the conflict between jQuery and PrototypeScript libraries. To fix it just use jQuery's `noConflict()` function:

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just
>   as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so
>   all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use
>   another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back
>   to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of
>   $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores
>   them.

1. Load the jQuery library first (at the top of the page)
2. Use `apex:includeScript` instead of `script` tag
3. Then use `noConflict()` function
4. Read this great topic [Using jQuery in a Visualforce Page](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/using-jquery-in-a-visualforce-page) from the developer force site

Yout page must look like this then:

```
<apex:page>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Scripts,'script/jquery-1.8.1.min.js')}" />

<script>
    jQuery.noConflict();

    // all other javascript stuff...
</script>

<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">
  <apex:tab label="Tab#1" id="tab1"></apex:tab>
  <apex:tab label="Tab#2" id="tab2"></apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

Comment: I'm using noConflict as "**var $ = jQuery.noConflict();**" from the beginning, but I replaced <script> with apex:includeScript, but the errors didn't gone.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help @mast0r , **I replaced $ with $x** then add noConflict function to $x and it works well.

Comment: @HasanKhatib Good!

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following test:
 - Remove the tabs, and check if the library works fine yet? There seems to be a problem with library in VF.

If it works fine then, it may be fixed by following:
 - Try using `jQuery.noConflict()` or move them beow '' (As said by [eyescream](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313628/eyescream))

- Manipulate the library and try to modify the function

[u may share the library for better clarity]