# Not able to use apex:tabPanel properly

Tags: visualforce, tab, tabpanel

I have created a Vf page in which i want to display 2 apex:pageBlock. I created the apex:tabPanel  as demo for the first time and tested it was working

content for tab one
        content for tab two

After this i made some changes to code and added my code to the existing code the tabs, now the tabs do not work as it was changing earlier. my code updated code

```
  <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theTabPanel"> 

    <apex:tab label="Offers" name="offers" id="offersId" immediate="true">
         <apex:pageBlock>
             <apex:ListViews type="Offers__c" />
         </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:tab>

    <apex:tab label="Submit IP for Approval" name="IPApproval" id="IPApprovalId">            
        <apex:pageBlock id="Approvalpanal" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Submit IP for Approval">
                <apex:form>
                    <c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="Offers__c" valueField="Id" targetField="{!targetField}" style="width:200px"/>  
                    <apex:InputField value="{!appr.IP_address__c}" style="width:300px;"/>
                </apex:form>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:form>
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!saveForApproval}" value="Save For Approval" />     
                </apex:form>                  
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>            
         </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:tab>



    </apex:tabPanel>`
```

Can anybody guide me what i am getting wrong.

Comment: I've copied + pasted your code into my dev org, and, minus the component and the IP address field, the tab structure appears to work for me? Can you clarify what "does not work" means for you, ie. what behaviour you are expecting?

Otherwise, I am inclined to suggest it is infact the component which is breaking the page.

Incidentally, the "selectedTab" attribute is not referencing a valid tab name, but that doesn't cause an error!

Comment: first tab is for offer view and second tab for Submit IP for Approval. I am only able to see the first tab not the second tab when i click on it. I have published the VF page as site. The url for site is -  http://onlinetest-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/apex/welcome?regId=a009000000SYYq7AAH

Comment: that is interesting. Try replacing your component line with something like just the text "component" and see if the tab comes back to life?

Comment: yes that is what i am trying to say that it work text. Not with pageblock and components in it.I tried this code http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_tabPanel.htm. This code works with text.

Comment: Hmm. Well tabPanels do work with both pageBlocks and components in them, no problem. So I would have to suggest that is is something IN the component markup that is breaking the code.

Comment: ya i found the issue i am using a component. I am using a component in my code - <c:AutoCompleteV2 allowClear="true" importJquery="true" labelField="Name" SObject="Offers__c" valueField="Id" targetField="{!targetField}" style="width:200px"/> when i remove this component it works. How can i resolve this issue.

Comment: We would have to know what exactly is in the component

Comment: Post component code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jQuery with apex:tabPanel in visualforce](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23159/using-jquery-with-apextabpanel-in-visualforce)

Answer (score 1):

if you are not able to switch between ur tabs use this code :

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

works fine for me

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I disagree @AlexTennant this is a well known solution to broken `tabPanel` components.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the code in the component you are including in one of the tabs. Everything about the tab layout looks fine, and it works in my Dev org (without the component - which of course I don't have).

You might find it easier to debug by copying (temporarily) the component (don't forget the controller!) into the page, and seeing how it behaves, bit by bit.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up a little bit on the answer by user8305, the underlying Javascript for the `apex:tabPanel` component relies on the `PrototypeScript` library that collides with the `$` global variable. So you need to call

```
jquery.noConflict();
```

in your code if the page contains `jQuery` otherwise you will break the `PrototypeScript` library. See [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23159/using-jquery-with-apextabpanel-in-visualforce) for detail.